# Is There A Way To Switch Between Multiple Audio Tracks Of MKV File In MediaFoundationReader?

Tags: c#, vb.net, naudio

I Am Searching For "Audio Track Switching" Between Multiple Audio Tracks In MediaFoundationReader But It Is Only Playing First Track Of MKV File.

I Searched In Browser Also, Searched In MediaFoundationReader Class To Get "Track Switch" Function But I Didn't Found. I Also Thought That It Will Come After Reading The File But It Is Always Taking First Track Of It. How Can I Switch Between Audio Tracks?